# How do I read this multiple parameter function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do I read and interpret the following line of a function:

`const canUser = (permission) => (permissions) => (guideSlug) => {`

This is the full function:

```
const canUser = (permission) => (permissions) => (guideSlug) => {
  if (!permissions) return false;

  const globalPermissions = permissions['*'] || {};
  const guidePermissions = permissions[guideSlug] || {};
  return globalPermissions[permission] || guidePermissions[permission] || false;
};
```

**Edit**

If I have an object like this:

```
export const checks = {
  canInvite: canUser('invite'),
}
```

I'm importing `canInvite` into my component and then running that function, giving it a `guideSlug` (string) to run the function. It works and checks out, I'm just not entirely sure how to understand what this does from the `const canUser` function definition

Any clarity here would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: What you're asking about is known as "currying" / "curried functions", in case that gives you a better jumping-off point in terms of research. Perhaps this is a good start: [What is 'currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying/36321)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if this was currying or not.

Comment: So it looks to me like the first function generates a single permission, then passes the single permission's value to the next function which I assume holds all permissions, that are then passed to the guideslug. It looks confusing to me as well, but I believe this is the logic. This is called a curried function. I don't have a lot of experience with them, but this should help you: https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-and-function-composition-2c208d774983

Answer (score 1):

`const foo = function(x) { return x + 1  }` can be loosely written as `const foo = x => x + 1`. The latter is called an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

So

```
const canUser = (permission) => (permissions) => (guideSlug) => {
  if (!permissions) return false;

  const globalPermissions = permissions['*'] || {};
  const guidePermissions = permissions[guideSlug] || {};
  return globalPermissions[permission] || guidePermissions[permission] || false;
};
```

is same as

```
const canUser = function(permission) {
  return function(permissions) {
    return function (guideSlug) {
      if (!permissions) return false;

      const globalPermissions = permissions['*'] || {};
      const guidePermissions = permissions[guideSlug] || {};
      return globalPermissions[permission] || guidePermissions[permission] || false;
    }
  }
};
```

This is called [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) or [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), both are kinda same I'm not sure which is the accurate term here.

Here's a case where it's useful...

```
const foo = (x, y) => { /* something to be done with x and y */ }
let x = foo(a,b);
let y = foo(a,c);
let z = foo(a,d);
```

Here as you can see there's a lot `a`s in the code which is kinda repetitive and less readable. Writing it in the following way solves the problem...

```
const foo = x => y => { /* something to be done with x and y */ }
let fooA = foo(a); // fooA is the `y => {}` function with `x = a` "partially applied"
let x = fooA(b);
let y = fooA(c);
let z = foo(a)(d); // you can still write it like this
```

Another advantage of such pattern is that you can pass around `fooA` to other function or if you want to store it in an abstraction of `a` like `const somethingRelevantToA = { foo: foo(a), bar: "some other prop of`a`" }`.

Also you are reusing the logic if you want something like `fooA` and `fooB` and they have something in common like...

```
const foo = x => y => {
  /* piece of code independent of x (this is being reused) */
  /* piece of code dependent only on y or x and y both */
}
```

So basically instead of writing `fooA` and `fooB` separately you are writing `foo` and thus reusing the logic.

Answer (score 0):

That piece of code can be rewritten in ES5 like this:

```
var canUser = function canUser(permission) {
  return function (permissions) {
    return function (guideSlug) {
      if (!permissions) return false;
      var globalPermissions = permissions['*'] || {};
      var guidePermissions = permissions[guideSlug] || {};
      return globalPermissions[permission] || guidePermissions[permission] || false;
    };
  };
};
```

This is called currying. Which, as state in [this article](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-es6-curry-functions-with-practical-examples-6ba2ced003b1), is the process of taking a function with multiple arguments and turning it into a sequence of functions each with only a single argument.

Assuming you have permissions and guideSlug defined somewhere,

```
var permissions = {'accounts':{'invite': true}, '*':{'home': '/'}};
var guideSlug = 'accounts';
```

You could call the function with:

```
canUser('invite')(permissions)(guideSlug)
```

```js
var permissions = {'accounts':{'invite': true}, '*':{'home': '/'}};
var guideSlug = 'accounts';

var canUser = function(permission) {
  return function(permissions) {
    return function (guideSlug) {
      if (!permissions) return false;

      var globalPermissions = permissions['*'] || {};
      var guidePermissions = permissions[guideSlug] || {};
  console.log(globalPermissions);
console.log(guidePermissions);
      return globalPermissions[permission] || guidePermissions[permission] || false;
    }
  }
};

console.log(canUser('invite')(permissions)(guideSlug));
```

One thing I noticed in your example is that it calls only the first function, which means it will return a function back to checks.canInvite when you call it here:

```
export const checks = {
  canInvite: canUser('invite'),
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed how to call this function.

Comment: Thank you, @Barmar ! Did my best.